# Error while creating trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
delimiter #

create trigger update_recharge_due_onrenewal after insert on recharge
for each row set
begin
update due_amount SET due_amount.amount=due_amount.amount-(select rate from
internet_package where recharge.package_id = internet_package.package_id)
where
due_advance.user_id = recharge.user_id;
end;#
```

Why is this showing error - unknown system variable 'begin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `for each row set` by `for each row`.